# how do I efficiently retrieve return value from function executed with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing, queue

I have multidimensional array which needs to be calculated with an imported function. (I am using jupyter notebook, so I exported the function to ipynb and imported it again) The function takes argument of 1 dimensional array.

```
#Function
def calculatespi(datagrid,q):
    date_time  = datagrid['time'][:]
    gridvalue = datagrid.values
    if np.isnan(np.sum(gridvalue)) != True:
        df_precip = pd.DataFrame({"Date": date_time,"precip":gridvalue})
        spi_prc = spi.SPI()
        spi3_grid = spi_prc.calculate(df_precip, 'Date', 'precip', freq = 'M', scale = 3, fit_type ="lmom", dist_type="gam")
        spi3 = spi3_grid['precip_scale_3_calculated_index'].values
    else:
        spi3 = np.empty((489))
        spi3[:] = np.nan
    q.put(spi3)

#Main Notebook
if name == "main":
    spipi = []
    processes = []
    for x in range (3):
        for y in range(3):
            q = multiprocessing.Queue()
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=calculatespi, args= (prcoba[:,x,y],q))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
            spipi.append(q.get())
     for process in processes:                                
         process.join()
```

After hundreds of attempt, finally I can retrieve the results from my problem but it took times longer than running it without using multiprocessing. What should I do?

Comment: Calling "q.get()" blocks until "calculatespi" puts the result in the queue.

Comment: where should I put it then? or am I using the wrong method? do you have any suggestion, sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) makes things much easier.

First, replace in `calculatespi` the `q.put(spi3)` by `return spi3` and remove the `q` parameter. Then the "main" code can be written as

```
#Main Notebook
if name == "main":

    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

    args = []
    
    for x in range (3):
        for y in range(3):
            args.append(prcoba[:,x,y])

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        spipi = list(executor.map(calculatespi, args))
```

The executor takes care about everything else.